# Pip could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Flask==0.10.1

Tags: python, flask, pip

This is totally bizarre, because this worked previously on my machine. I forked a repo from github, created a new virtualenv, and tried

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I received the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Storing debug log for failure in /home/michael/.pip/pip.log
```

And the following was stored in my debug log:

```
/home/michael/git/blueprint_ex/env/bin/pip run on Thu Dec 24 09:57:08 2015
Downloading/unpacking Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/Flask/
  URLs to search for versions for Flask==0.10.1 (from -r     requirements.txt (line 1)):
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/Flask/0.10.1
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/Flask/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/Flask/0.10.1
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/Flask/0.10.1: 404 Client Error: Not Found
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/Flask/0.10.1 when looking for download links for Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/git/blueprint_ex/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/michael/git/blueprint_ex/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 304, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/home/michael/git/blueprint_ex/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/home/michael/git/blueprint_ex/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
 DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

My requirements.txt file looks like

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-WTF==0.11
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
SQLAlchemy==1.0.10
WTForms==2.1
Werkzeug==0.11.3
argparse==1.2.1
coverage==3.7.1
itsdangerous==0.24
nose==1.3.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is? I was previously able to install Flask on a different virtualenv on the same machine, so this is particularly frustrating. Moreover, I tried

```
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

and this worked fine.

```
pip install Flask
```

or

```
pip install Flask==0.10.1
```

give me the same error messages as above.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue today, except with MarkupSafe==0.23, 
and in an earlier docker build command today, on the same machine using the same network, it worked just fine. I suspect a transient network or server issue, but that is just a wild guess.

Comment: It seems to have been a server issue because it eventually rectified itself...

Answer (score 0):

Pls test whether you can access "https://pypi.python.org/simple/Flask/". Maybe you need to set proxy for https.